Different actions in context menu - confusing or no?

How to handle table content menus?

(Never mind the red arrow here please)
Currently for each line we display a 3-dot-menu on the right with actions the user can take with the selected data row; e.g. if it's a list of users, they can delete, remove, etc.
but in some cases only for SOME users certain actions are available (or none at all!), e.g. for users with admin status, deletion is not possible.
How to handle this?

always display all actions, regardless of whether they can be done or not - then on click display why it's not possible in that particular case
only display the actions that are possible
and also, do not display the 3 dots at all if no action can be taken?
or sth else?

My main concern is that users won't know why certain actions are not possible at certain times and/or why the menu is missing in some cases; since this is not really explained anywhere.
However, when I think about action menus like in MS Word or others, it's real common that only the available actions are displayed. So it might not be that bad after all. But then again, the differences in items might be more obvious than in my case here (all in the list are users, just different features e.g. roles causing different actions to be available)
Glad for every input here!  thanks in advance!

Please add mockup images to help understand the context better and find better answers.

Displaying unnecessary things increases cognitive load especially when we are talking about CTAs. The user needs to be more careful with CTAs before deciding anything. By displaying more options, it first makes user read more - requires paying attention, reading and comprehension till the user figures out what exactly is going to happen if you click on that CTA. Then comes the disappointment message that the user is not qualified and does not have enough access rights to carry out the operation - more reading time and disappointment.
It is a good UX strategy to never blame the user that he/she did something wrong or is not qualified enough. If displaying those options do not provide any/enough value to the user, please do not display them.

I get the idea and agree it's probably not a nice experience. However, compared to the experience I have when I want to do sth (e.g.) delete a user but I can't and I literally have no place to look up WHY (we don't have any docs or sth explaining e.g. admins can't be deleted) and just do guessing? However, thanks a lot, it helped me to think abt the user journey more again

I disagree with @ren. He's right when, for example, a 3D editing program where every click of a menu item causes a drop down of a huge screen filling list.
But in this case, with only 3 or 4 familiar and easily distinguishable options, like add, delete, etc; It's easier if the user see the same drop down she expects, with invalid entries grayed out. If the user mouseoves  a grayed out entry, pop up  explanatory  text giving a status of the grayed out option ("cannot delete admin").
For records for which there are no options, gray out the ..., but provide a similar pop up explaining that  there are no options.

Yeah I just don't see a good way to explain the user anyhow else why they can't do sth for this user... But then again I need a way different than hovering since we support mobile too - so I end up at pop-ups ‍♀️

Yes, I hate it when a format restricts what you really want to do. What I would do in your case is leave them all active with some grayed out. When they click a gray one, you throw a fade-out pop-up.

But do users actually click on greed put items is my follow up question then  i mean hover totally solved this, since hovering 100% they will do just when contemplating why it's greyed out but actually clicking? I'm not convinced  but probably best to just test this out and get feedback
